# PHP Extra whitespace?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, response, whitespace

I'm using AJAX to process my ChangePassword class, which extends my DataProcessor class. Everything I get from my AJAX response is somehow having a huge whitespace added before it, maybe equivalent to 10 spaces. The following is my ChangePassword class:

```
<?php
require_once "../support/RequiredClasses.php";
class ChangePassword extends DataProcessor {
    private $_old_password;
    private $_new_password_1;
    private $_new_password_2;
    private $_password_enc;
    //============================================================================================================================================ Class Constrcutor
    public function __construct($_old_password,$_new_password_1,$_new_password_2){
        try {
            $_DM                     = new DataManager();
            $this->_conn             = $_DM->connect();
            $this->_old_password     = filter_var($_old_password,  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $this->_new_password_1   = filter_var($_new_password_1,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $this->_new_password_2   = filter_var($_new_password_2,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                if (!$_old_password OR !$_new_password_1 OR !$_new_password_2)
                                                                     {throw new Exception("You have not filled in all of the fields.");}
                if ($this->_new_password_1 != $this->_new_password_2){throw new Exception("The two new passwords you entered do not match.");}
                if (!isset($this->_new_password_1[7]))               {throw new Exception("Your new password must be at least 8 digits in length.");}
            $this->_old_password_enc = $_DM->encrypt($this->_old_password,1,$_SESSION["user_email"]);   
                if (!$this->verifyPassword())                        {throw new Exception("The old password you entered was incorrect.");}
            $this->_new_password_enc = $_DM->encrypt($this->_new_password_1,1,$_SESSION["user_email"]); 
            $this->_access            = $this->makeChanges();
        } // end try
        catch (Exception $_exception){$this->_errors[] = $_exception->getMessage();}
    } // end __construct
    public function ChangePassword(){$this->__construct($_old_password,$_new_password_1,$_new_password_2);}
    //============================================================================================================================================ Changing Password
    protected function makeChanges(){
        $_update = $this->_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE user_id=?");
            if (!$_update){return FALSE;}
        $_update->bind_param("si",$this->_new_password_enc,$_SESSION["user_id"]);
        $_update->execute();
        $_update->free_result();
        return TRUE;
    } // end makeChanges
    //============================================================================================================================================ Verifying Old Password
    private function verifyPassword(){
        $_verify = $this->_conn->prepare("SELECT role_id FROM users WHERE user_id=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
        $_verify->bind_param("is",$_SESSION["user_id"],$this->_old_password_enc);
        $_verify->execute();
        $_verify->bind_result($_fetched_result);
        $_verify->fetch();
        $_verify->free_result();
        return ($_fetched_result) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    } // end verifyPassword
} // end class ChangePassword
if (isset($_POST["q"]) AND $_POST["q"] == 1){
    $_ChangePassword = new ChangePassword($_POST["old_password"],$_POST["new_password_1"],$_POST["new_password_2"]);
    if (count($_ChangePassword->_errors)){echo $_ChangePassword->returnErrors();}
    else {
        echo "Success changing password.";
    } // end else
} // end if ?>
```

The next is my DataProcessor class:

```
<?php
abstract class DataProcessor {
    public $_conn;              // database connection
    public $_access;            // whether or not the user has access
    public $_errors = array();  // class-generated errors
    //============================================================================================================================================ Returning a String of All Errors
    public function returnErrors(){
        $_error_string = "";
        foreach ($this->_errors as $_error){$_error_string .= $_error;}
        return $_error_string;
    } // end returnErrors
} // end abstract class DataProcessor ?>
```

Finally, my AJAX code:

```
var request;
prepareAJAX();
function prepareAJAX(){
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} // end prepareAJAX
function submitChangePassword(){
var old_password   = document.getElementById("cp_old_password").value;
var new_password_1 = document.getElementById("cp_new_password_1").value;
var new_password_2 = document.getElementById("cp_new_password_2").value;
var vars           = "q=1&old_password="+old_password+"&new_password_1="+new_password_1+"&new_password_2="+new_password_2;
request.open("POST","../classes/class.ChangePassword.php");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
        var return_data = request.responseText;
        alert(return_data);
        var type = (return_data.charAt(0) == "1") ? "error" : "success";
        lightboxNotice("cp",type,return_data);
    } // end if
} // end function
request.send(vars);
} // end submitChangePassword
function lightboxNotice(prefix,type,message){
switch(type){
    case "error":
        document.getElementById(prefix+"_lightbox_notice").className = "ligthbox_notice lightbox_error";
        break;
    case "message":
        document.getElementById(prefix+"_lightbox_notice").className = "ligthbox_notice lightbox_message";
        break;
    case "success":
        document.getElementById(prefix+"_lightbox_notice").className = "ligthbox_notice lightbox_success";
        break;
} // end switch
document.getElementById(prefix+"_lightbox_notice").style.display    = "block";
document.getElementById(prefix+"_lightbox_notice").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById(prefix+"_lightbox_notice").style.opacity    = 1;
printNotice(prefix,type,message);
} // end lightboxNotice
function printNotice(prefix,type,message){
switch(type){
    case "error":
        document.getElementById(prefix+"_notice").className = "notice_error";
        break;
    case "message":
        document.getElementById(prefix+"_notice").className = "notice_message";
        break;
    case "success":
        document.getElementById(prefix+"_notice").className = "notice_success";
        break;
} // end switch
document.getElementById(prefix+"_notice").style.display    = "block";
document.getElementById(prefix+"_notice").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById(prefix+"_notice").style.opacity    = 1;
document.getElementById(prefix+"_notice").innerHTML        = message;
} // end printError
```

Comment: on your page, you are probably outputting some html input text and password fields to send via the ajax, correct? I would guess that you have some large amount of whitespace that is already in the input. However, rather than guessing, you should post the html that the ajax is acting on so we can see that also.

Comment: that's a lot of code to go through.  Can you explain what efforts you have made to debug this? Can you narrow down where the problem is to a few lines of code?

Comment: Check for a bunch of whitespace before `<?php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only white-space, why not just use [trim()?](http://php.net/trim)

You should also probably trim the javascript

```
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
        var return_data = request.responseText;
        return_data = return_data.trim()
```